# Write a newline in a textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am writing a little JS script which produces an output on multiple lines, and I want to display this output in a `textarea` with id `message`. I know that a textarea does not interpret html. Since the textarea is a `form` tag, I tried the following to display my result:

- `$("#message").val("test\\ntest");` writes `test\ntest` in the textarea
- `$("#message").val("test&#13;&#10;test");` writes `test&#13;&#10;test` in the textarea

But since it is also an open-close tag, I assumed that the `.html()` attribute was valid on it, and it seems to be, but when I do the following:

- `$("#message").html("test\\ntest");`
- `$("#message").html("test&#13;&#10;test");`

it does not update anything visible in the `textarea`, but when I look into the console and inspect the element, I see the well formated text between the two tags.

The only way I was able to do it is the write directly the text in the `textarea`, like so:

`<textarea id="message>test&#13;&#10;test</textarea>`

which produces a well formated output, but since I want my JS script to update it it is not relevant.

I read a lot of topics and suggestions, but none seems to answer to my specific question: Is there any way I can modify in Javascript the value of a textarea displaying text on multiple lines?

**tl;dr**

I tried the following (fill all the textareas before testing):

```js
$("#button").click( function() {
  $("#ta1").val("test\\ntest");
  $("#ta2").val("test&#13;&#10;test");
  $("#ta3").html("test\\ntest");
  $("#ta4").html("test&#13;&#10;test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Fill all the textareas before testing</p>
<button id="button">Test</button>

<p>Test 1 : </p>
<textarea id="ta1"></textarea></br>
<p>Test 2 : </p>
<textarea id="ta2"></textarea></br>
<p>Test 3 : </p>
<textarea id="ta3"></textarea></br>
<p>Test 4 : </p>
<textarea id="ta4"></textarea></br>
<p>Test 5 : </p>
<textarea id="ta5">test&#13;&#10;test</textarea>
```

and none of thoses tests are allowing me to replace the `textarea` value with multiline text.

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JJJ correctly states in comments, just include `\n` in the value:

```js
$("#button").click( function() {
  $("#ta1").val("test\ntest");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Test</button>

<p>Test:</p>
<textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
```

Your attempts fail because:

- `"\\"` is interpreted as a backslash in a string, then `n` is just a `"n"`. There is no newline.
- `val` will not interpret HTML.
- same as the first case
- This actually works - for the initial value. When `<textarea>` is initialised, its value is its content. After it is first edited, it's the `value` property that matters, and the content is not relevant any more. Which is why it works if you haven't edited the `<textarea>`, but not if you did.

The first case was closest to working, you just went overboard with backslashes.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, it seems so obvious... Thanks a lot to both of you.